# Как получить текущего пользователя в models.py

Tags: python, django, users

Требуется получить текущего пользователя в `models.py`:

```
class Dialog(models.Model):
    # Модель

    def get_msg(self): # Метод
        return Messages.objects.get(dialog=self, user=user # Текущий пользователь)
```

Как это сделать и можно ли это сделать вообще?

Comment: свяжите модель `Dialog` с пользователем и вызывайте как `self.user`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге проблема решилась установкой модуля `django-currentuser` (https://pypi.org/project/django-currentuser/).

**settings.py:**

```
    MIDDLEWARE = [
     ...
    'django_currentuser.middleware.ThreadLocalUserMiddleware',
]
```

**models.py**

```
from django_currentuser.middleware import (
get_current_user, get_current_authenticated_user)


  class Dialog(models.Model):
      # Модель
      def get_msg(self): # Метод
          user=get_current_user()
          return Messages.objects.get(dialog=self, user=user)
```

Comment: `, user` не нужен если есть `user=get_current_user()`

Answer (score 0):

У модели нет своего пользователя (если вы не привязали его вручную, конечно). Вы можете получить информацию о пользователе, который делает запрос. Делается это в `views.py` следующим образом:

```py
def view_name(request):
    user = request.user 
    # мы получили информацию о пользователе, который воспользовался представлением.
```

Обращаю внимание, что `request.user` может возвращать как конкретного пользователя, так и `None`, если человек, производящий запрос к представлению, не авторизирован.
Теперь уже в представлении вы можете сделать запрос к своей модели. Можно сделать что-то вроде этого:

```
class Dialog(models.Model):
    # Модель
    def get_msg(self, user): # Метод
        return Messages.objects.get(dialog=self, user=user)
```

Тогда можно при обращении из представления передать пользователя в функцию `get_msg`

Comment: Данный метод(get_msg) вызывается не во views.py, а в шаблоне

Comment: @АлександрКоваленко если вам нужно в шаблоне знать, что за пользователь зашёл на страницу, то как раз во `views.py` нужно передать `user` в шаблон, как контекстный параметр

Comment: Нет. Мне нужно получить пользователя именно в `models.py`, чтобы уже оттуда вызвать функцию